# My pegasus R6 - my Mac says it requires repair

Tags: hard-drive, repair, imac

My Mac says my Pegasus R6 disk is corrupt and not repairable Downloaded utility and updated to recent firmware - still not able to fix

Comment: What about "not repairable" don't you understand?

Comment: The Pegasus utility says all drives are fine and operating. The Mac says they are not. There have been issues with the Mac not reading this external hard drive. Anyone had issues with this? This is a 6X2 Tb hard drive. I have backed everything up.My Mac tells me to reformat. I am not going to reformat and reinstall all this data if it is a Mac issues and not really a hard drive issue.

Comment: Is it a RAID drive?

Comment: yes it is a raid - I used the factory configuration I think Raid 5?